# How to use associated Model as datasource for DataView

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a Model structure as shown below and I want to know how to use the Bookings array as the datasource of my DataView.

Model Structure:

```
Client
  ClientId
  Name
  Bookings (HasManyAssociation)
  Contacts (HasManyAssociation)
  AjaxProxy
    JsonReader (ImplicitIncludes is set to true so child models are created with one call)

Booking
  BookingNodeId
  BookingDetails

Contact
  ContactNodeId
  ContactDetails
```

The above gives me a data structure as follows:

```
Client
  Bookings[
    Booking
    Booking
  ]
  Contacts[
    Contact
    Contact
  ]
```

What I want to be able to do is either, create a Store from my Bookings array and then use that store as the datasource for my DataView OR directly use the Bookings array as the datasource (I don't really care how I do it to be honest).

If I setup the AjaxProxy on my Booking model it works fine but then obviously I cannot automatically create my Client and Contacts when I load my JSON.

It seems to me to make sense that the Client model, being the top level model hierarchically, is the one to load the data.

**EDIT:**

I figured it out as follows (with special thanks to handet87 below for his dataview.setStore() pointer).

The key in this case is to know that creating the relationship actually sets up another store called, in this case BookingsStore and ContactsStore.
All I needed to do was dataview.setStore("BookingsStore")

Comment: Chris, there it go my recommendation: avoid associations. There will be pain in future, really don´t use it.

Answer (score 2):

Get the data from server with an Ajax Request, then you can use the parsed json data as an array. Define a store and add that data to that store. Lastly, assign that store to your dataview.

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
url: '/Default.aspx',
params: {
    'params': itemId
},
failure: function (response) {
    Ext.Msg.alert('error', 'error');
},
success: function (response, opts) {
    var jsonData = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
    //now you can access jsonData.Bookings

    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: 'MyApp.model.Client'         
    });

    store.setData(jsonData.Bookings);

    dataview.setStore(store);
}});
```

The main methodology will be like that. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help handet87 but it's not quite what I meant (though your dataview.setStore() pointer is worthy of a thumb up). I've actually figured it out and edited my answer in-case it helps others in the future.